# How to store values in a new array by using replace method?

Tags: java, arrays, replaceall

I want to store non "h" values in an array. So to give you a background, I need to make a basic cash register that accepts 5 items in an array with a price on them. Nevertheless, some items will have HST(tax) included with them. To know which items have tax and which don't. The user will press h or H before or after entering the dollar amount. I have stored the values with the HST in an array, but how would I store the non-HST values?

**NOTE**: I tried doing it as the same as my "h" values, but it would not work that's why I am confused

**I cannot use Arrayslist or any other array methods**

Sample input:

```
4.565H
H2.3435
4.565h
5.234
5.6576h
```

Sample Output:

```
HST Values:
4.565
2.3435
4.565
5.6576

Non-HST Values
5.234
```

---

This is What I tried But it won't work:

```
  // Import scanner class
 import java.util.Scanner;

// Create class and method
 class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
 Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Press any key to start");
 String key = inp.nextLine();
 System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
 System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

// Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
int counter = 0;
int index = 0;
int index2 = 0;

// Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
Double[] numbers = new Double[5];
Double[] numbers2 = new Double[5];

// Create a boolean variable to use it in the while loop
boolean go = true;

while (go) {
  String value = inp.nextLine();
  value = value.toLowerCase();

  // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
  int indexOfh = value.indexOf('h');

  boolean containsh = indexOfh == 0 || indexOfh == (value.length() - 1);

  if (containsh) { // Validate h at beginning or end
    numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
    index++;
    System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
  }else{
    numbers2[index2] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("","")); // value.replace is an issue
  }
  counter++;
  if (counter == 5) {
    go = false;
  }
}
System.out.println("\nHST Values:");

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  // If there is any absence of values, print the HST values
  if (numbers[i] != null) {
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
  }
}
System.out.println("\nNon-HST Values:");
for (int x = 0; x < numbers2.length; x++){
  if (numbers2[x] != null){
  System.out.println(numbers2[x]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Things I changed:

1. `numbers2[index2] = Double.parseDouble(value);` // no need to replace anything here
2. `index2++` , I see you increment `index` but not `index2`
3. When you print HST and non-HST value, you do not need to go till `numbers.length` or `numbers2.length`, because you know the values of `index` and `index2`, you already know the values in each array.

If you do this way then you do not need to do null check when you are printing.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press any key to start");
    String key = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
    System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

    int counter = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

   Double[] numbers = new Double[5];
    Double[] numbers2 = new Double[5];

   boolean go = true;

    while (go) {
        String value = inp.nextLine();
        value = value.toLowerCase();

        // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
        int indexOfh = value.indexOf('h');

        boolean containsh = indexOfh == 0 || indexOfh == (value.length() - 1);

        if (containsh) { // Validate h at beginning or end
            numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
            index++;
            System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
        } else {
            numbers2[index2] = Double.parseDouble(value); // changed here
            index2++; //added this line
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter == 5) {
            go = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nHST Values:");

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { // changed here

        // no need to do null check now
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);

    }
    System.out.println("\nNon-HST Values:");
    for (int x = 0; x < index2; x++) { // changed here
        // no need to do null check now
            System.out.println(numbers2[x]);

    }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the failed parsing of non-HST values is generally resolved in [@Anon's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295512/13279831), however there are some other points to make code cleaner:

- provide a constant instead of hardcoded length of arrays `5`
- remove redundant messages
- improve logic, rename variables and remove redundant ones
- improve handling of errors in user's input
- use String `matches` method with a case-insensitive regexp to check if the item is HST or not

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    final int SIZE = 5;
    
    // Create a double array variable, and set the limit
    double[] hstItems = new double[SIZE];
    double[] nonHstItems = new double[SIZE];

    // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
 
    System.out.printf("Enter up to %d HST or non-HST items%n", SIZE);

    // Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
    int counter = 0;
    int hstCount = 0;
    int nonHstCount = 0;

    while (counter++ < SIZE) {
        String value = inp.nextLine();
        try {
            if (value.matches("(?i)(h.+|.+h)")) {
                hstItems[hstCount++] = Double.parseDouble(value.replaceAll("(?i)h", ""));
                System.out.println("HST will be taken into account for this value");
            } else {
                nonHstItems[nonHstCount++] = Double.parseDouble(value);
                System.out.println("No HST is taken into account for this value");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.printf("Failed to parse value: %s, error: %s, please try again%n", value, ex.getMessage());
            counter--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nHST Values:");
    for (int i = 0; i < hstCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(hstItems[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\nNon-HST Values:");
    for (int i = 0; i < nonHstCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(nonHstItems[i]);
    }
}
```